# Syncfusion PDF Viewer Gray upon firebase deploy, Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, syncfusion

I'm trying to display PDF using https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer, and it works in debug mode. But when I deploy it to firebase hosting, it's just gray screen.

I've already added the necessary pdfjs script in index.html, as stated in the documentation. I'm also releasing the app on Web platform only. Anyone help?

EDIT:

Availed for their Free Community Licensing Program and got a key.

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/how-to-register-in-an-application#flutter

Tried to Register it, however, it is not required anymore according to the documentation. So the issue is not in the licensing.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: They have a Free Community License Program that I've already availed, but I'm not sure where to attach the license key.

Comment: Also it states in their documentation that registering a license key is not required anymore for Flutter. So the issue is not in the licensing.

Comment: You don't need to *register*, but I'm pretty sure you're still *subject* to the license.  And that's five people and you're out of bounds.